# как убить процесс c#

Tags: c#, процесс

Как постоянно убивать допустим один из этих процессов, если он был замечен? Пробовал такой код, 1й раз срабатывает как надо, на второй выдает ошибку

```
    static string[] procs =
    {
        "chrome", "skype", "explorer"
    };


    public static void kill()
    {
            while (true)
            {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach (Process chk in processes)
                {
                    foreach (string s in procs)
                    {
                        if (chk.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))
                        {
                            chk.Kill();
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Текст ошибки приведите

Comment: `while (true)`? Вы вот так прямо гоняете холостой цикл?

Answer (score 0):

Текста ошибки вы не предоставили, но так как я потомственная гадалка, я предполагаю, что ошибка выпадает на

```
chk.Kill();
```

Скорее всего происходит исключение из-за отказа доступа.

1. Я бы порекомендовал для начала добавить блоки try/catch внутри второго цилка foreach для того, чтобы избежать лишних крашей.
2. Добавьте в цикл while(true) Thread.Sleep чтобы избежать неимоверное сжирание цп
3. Если ничего не помогает можете попробовать запустить программу от имени администратора или с наивысшими правами.(Чтобы каждый раз не запускать от имени администратора можете прописать в манифесте [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

Окончательный вариант кода

```
static string[] procs =
    {
        "chrome", "skype", "explorer"
    };


public static void kill()
{
        while (true)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process chk in processes)
            {
                foreach (string s in procs)
                {
                    try
                    {
                      if (chk.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))
                      {
                          chk.Kill();
                      }
                      else
                      {

                      }
                   } catch {}
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

    }
```